# Is there a way to snap current frame to selection?

Tags: nla-editor

When I using NLA or Graph Editor or something related to the timeline,I can only snap the selection to current frame,but if I want to align selection-B to the end of selection-A,the only way I can do is manually move current frame to the end of selection-A, and snap the selection-B to current frame. Is there a way to replace such manual alignment?
[image]

Comment: do you mean like snapping in vse?

Comment: yes,in vse,hold Ctrl will snap the current frame to video.